# scraping data using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hello I'm new to this,

But I wrote the following script to scrape the following standings 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/98FPr.png

website: http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/spanish-la-liga/table

Im trying to print the position and team name. Team name prints fine, but for the position I keep getting none. Can anyone help me get over that please?

```
    import urllib2
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = "http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/spanish-la-liga/table"

    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

    for row in soup ("table" , {"class" : "table-stats"})[0].tbody("tr"):
        tds = row("td")

    print tds[1].string, tds[2].string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have easily found out the problem with an interactive Python shell.

The problem is that `tds[1]` (or in full, `soup("table", {"class":"table-stats"})[0].tbody("tr")[0]("td")[1]`, just to name one) has the form

```
<td class="position"><span class="no-movement">No movement</span> <span class="position-number">1</span></td>
```

And its `.string` attribute (i.e., the `.string` attribute of the `position` class) is `None`. You can extract the actual number with `tds[1].contents[2].string`.

Fully corrected script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/spanish-la-liga/table"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
for row in soup ("table" , {"class" : "table-stats"})[0].tbody("tr"):
    tds = row("td")
    print tds[1].contents[2].string, tds[2].string
```

Output:

```
1 Barcelona
2 Real Madrid
3 Valencia
4 Atl Madrid
5 Sevilla
6 Villarreal
7 Málaga
8 Ath Bilbao
9 Espanyol
10 Real Sociedad
11 Celta de Vigo
12 Rayo Vallecano
13 Getafe
14 Eibar
15 Elche
16 Almería
17 Deportivo de La Coruña
18 Levante
19 Granada CF
20 Córdoba
```